# asp.net repeater merge columns dynamically

Tags: asp.net, merge, repeater

I have a repeater in my ASP.net page. I want to merge the columns which have same text. This should happen dynamically when I bind a datatable. I have searched a lot for this. But, without success. I doubt whether it is possible with a repeater. I would also like to mention that there are also image buttons and check boxes in each row.

This is my repeater source:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" onitemcommand="rpt1_ItemCommand">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>As On</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblRelayName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTimeFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnStatus" runat="server" 
                        ImageUrl="~/img/btnGet.jpg" 
                        CommandName="Change"  style="width: 36px; border-width: 0px; margin-top: -4px; vertical-align: middle;" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked="true" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

This is how I fill the repeater:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rpt1.DataSource = GetData();
    rpt1.DataBind();
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ItemName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("Price");

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Orange";
    dr["Date"] = "01/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "50";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Orange";
    dr["Date"] = "02/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "51";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Orange";
    dr["Date"] = "03/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "55";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Apple";
    dr["Date"] = "01/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "95";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Apple";
    dr["Date"] = "03/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "98";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ItemName"] = "Banana";
    dr["Date"] = "01/01/2015";
    dr["Price"] = "48";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the simplified code.  But I don't understand.  Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "merge the columns which have the same text".  What would you expect the final output to look like?

Comment: Thanks Rajeev Goel for responding. I don't have enough reputation to add images. So, I ll try to explain it. The final output should be a table, that has its first column's 3 rows(orange) merged. Then, the next 2 rows(apple) merged.  But, this should be done dynamically, i.e. if the row1-cell1 == row2-cell1, merge them. may be in the _ItemDataBound event. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But if you merge the rows, what are you going to show in the Date and Price columns?  For example, for "Orange", the Price could be 50, 51, or 55.  So which price do you want to show?

Comment: No, its like this:-  price of Orange on 01/01/2015 = 50, on 02/01/2015 = 51, ......

Comment: Okay, so you would still expect to show three rows in your table for "Orange", but in the first column, the text "Orange" would only appear in the first row, and there would be no text in the first column of the 2nd and 3rd rows.  Correct?

Comment: yes that what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I was able to get it to look like this.  I think this is what you wanted:

[image]

But I had to make significant changes to your code to make this work.  Firstly, DataTable and DataRow are pretty outdated classes ... they don't support Linq, etc.  So I switched to just using plain objects.  Secondly, you are going to need to do the merging in your code-behind.  It's still "dynamic" in the sense that you won't have to change the raw data that is coming back from the server.  But you will have "process" the data before binding to the Repeater control.  Here's what I ended up with:

**.ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="10" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>As On</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style='vertical-align: top; display: <%# ((bool) Eval("IsFirstRowWithThisItemName")) ? "" : "none" %>;' 
                rowspan="<%# Eval("CountOfProductsWithThisItemName") %>">
                <asp:Label ID="lblRelayName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimeFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ShortDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PriceDisplay") %>'></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnStatus" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="~/img/btnGet.jpg"
                    CommandName="Change" Style="width: 36px; border-width: 0px; margin-top: -4px; vertical-align: middle;" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked="true" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.ASPX.CS**

```
public partial class About : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rpt1.DataSource = this.GetMergedData(this.GetData());
        rpt1.DataBind();

    }

    private List<Product> GetMergedData(List<Product> allProducts)
    {
        List<Product> mergedProducts = new List<Product>();

        var groupingsByName =
            allProducts
            .GroupBy(product => product.ItemName);

        foreach (var groupingByName in groupingsByName)
        {
            Product firstProduct = groupingByName.First();
            firstProduct.CountOfProductsWithThisItemName = groupingByName.Count();
            firstProduct.IsFirstRowWithThisItemName = true;
            mergedProducts.Add(firstProduct);

            mergedProducts.AddRange(groupingByName.Skip(1));
        }

        return mergedProducts;
    }

    private List<Product> GetData()
    {
        return new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product("Orange", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015"), 50),
            new Product("Orange", DateTime.Parse("02/01/2015"), 51),
            new Product("Orange", DateTime.Parse("03/01/2015"), 55),
            new Product("Apple", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015"), 95),
            new Product("Apple", DateTime.Parse("03/01/2015"), 98),
            new Product("Banana", DateTime.Parse("01/01/2015"), 48),
        };
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ShortDate { get { return this.Date.ToShortDateString();  } }
    public string PriceDisplay { get { return this.Price.ToString("C");  } }

    public int CountOfProductsWithThisItemName { get; set; }
    public bool IsFirstRowWithThisItemName { get; set; }

    public Product(string itemName, DateTime date, decimal price)
    {
        this.ItemName = itemName;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Price = price;
    }
}
```