# Merging cell of equal value in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, merge

Currently I try to use Repeater WebControl in order to display a table that list out all possible component. Below is my table;

[image]

Right now I try to merged cells in Group Code and Group Description column that have the same value. Below is my merging cell code, noted that the code is in class;

```
public void repeaterRowSpan(string repeaterID, string columnID)
{
    var pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler;
    Control ctrl = ((Page)pageHandler).Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder3").FindControl(repeaterID);
    Repeater repeaterName = (Repeater)ctrl;

    for (int i = repeaterName.Items.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        HtmlTableCell oCell_previous = (HtmlTableCell)repeaterName.Items[i - 1].FindControl(columnID);
        HtmlTableCell oCell = (HtmlTableCell)repeaterName.Items[i].FindControl(columnID);

        oCell.RowSpan = (oCell.RowSpan == -1) ? 1 : oCell.RowSpan;
        oCell_previous.RowSpan = (oCell_previous.RowSpan == -1) ? 1 : oCell_previous.RowSpan;

        if (oCell.InnerText == oCell_previous.InnerText)
        {
            oCell.InnerText = "";
            oCell_previous.RowSpan += oCell.RowSpan;
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow the code manage to delete the same value in the column but maintain the rowspan. When I debugged, the oCell_previous.RowSpan return '2' so the code itself working fine. Below is the result of merging;

[image]

How can I modified my code in such way it will merged the cell?

In your opinion, between Repeater and GridView which is most suitable to show data in table form in this project? In my understanding, Repeater is most suitable since it faster than GridView. GridView is only suitable if you have edit function to go with your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net repeater merge columns dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999444/asp-net-repeater-merge-columns-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented using the `OnDataBound` event.  The OnDataBound event of the GridView is executed after the GridView is populated with the records. Executed a loop in reverse over the GridView Rows and then the common Cells are identified and merged into single cell.

Below sample code merges the first & second columns (assuming that there are redundant values by comparing the above row(s)),

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more info.

```
protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
        GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[i - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            if (row.Cells[j].Text == previousRow.Cells[j].Text)
            {
                if (previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[j].RowSpan == 0)
                    {
                        previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan += 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = row.Cells[j].RowSpan + 1;
                    }
                    row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code can only be used for GridView, my current code is for Repeater. As far as I know, Repeater don't have OnDataBound event. I'm using Repeater for my project as Repeater is more faster loading info than GridView. Are you suggest that Repeater cannot merged cells while GridView have that capabilities? If so, I might change to Gridview.

Comment: My mistake. Yes, the repeater can also afford to merge. Can you try this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999444/asp-net-repeater-merge-columns-dynamically.